# Controllers by page or controllers by entity?

Tags: php, laravel, controllers, application-design

I'm building in Laravel a self managed institutional website with some dynamic content like: products, news, users, etc., and I came up with a doubt about controllers and best practices.

While some pages are fully static (about, services info, ...) others, like products listing, are dynamic.

I'm not sure if I have to create controllers by page or entities. Eg:

```
ProductController => shows the page for a single product
ProductsController => shows the page for listing all the products
SearchController => shows the page for searching products
AboutController => shows the about page
ServicesController => shows the page for listing services

vs

ProductsController => shows the page for single and multiple products, and the search products page
PagesController / StaticController => shows all static pages (like "about" and "services")
```

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller will be class responsible for displaying entity values. So You should use your second example, controllers by entity.

You have for example functionality "Show my static site", this is one functionality, one responsibility, so one class/controller. If you divide it for many controllers, that gave You duplicate code.

Comment: So every controller is responsible for showing all pages for the same entity? Also all CRUD's entity operations?

Comment: You have for example functionality "Show my static site", this is one functionality, one responsibility, so one class/controller. If you divide it for many controllers, that gave You duplicate code. Yes also CRUD, but remember don't pack logic into controllers

Answer (score 1):

You can create just one route and one method for static pages, which will use slugs to get data for static pages from DB.

```
Route::get('\static\{slug}', 'ContentController@buildStaticPage');

public function buildStaticPage($slug)
{
    ....
```

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm doing now. Just wanted to know the best approach regarding controllers concept.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no "better" and "worse" since it always depends on your usecase. However, as laravel intends with

```
php artisan make:controller MyController --resource
```

A controller COULD represent the basic crud functionallity regarding one entity. Therefore probably approach 2 of your question is what you are looking for.

As @Alexey Mezenin proposed you can ofcourse create a controller which is dedicated to return your static pages - or you could even return them inline in your reouts

```
Route::get('my-static', function() { return view('static.my-page' ); });
```

Comment: I've always thought in controllers more like "a lawyer a client". I mean, the purpose of them is to fulfill a single view. The reason is that it might become  a Linux kernel if handling every action for a single entity and I hate this type of things.

Comment: As mentioned there is not the "one-and-only-way" you are free to do so, however I always had the feeling that you run into tons of controllers if you do so. 
But if you have a usecase where you have a lot of endpoints for a single view then it might make sense for you to have a controller per view.